# Grouping data for one row

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, pivot, grouping

I have a data in database that looks like this:

[image]

and I need it to look like this:

[image]

What should the query look like? So basically I always need the MAX date from actions and only to show one row for each attribute. I'm using SQL Developer. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a *conditional case* expression and aggregation.

```
select Attribute, 
    Max(case when action='produced' then date end) as Produced_Date,
    Max(case when action='sold' then date end) as Sold_Date
from t
group by Attribute
```